# Common source circuit with current source and diode connected load

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, cmos

Could anyone explain why the output bias voltage of the common source in figure a is not well defined and needs a common mode feedback while the circuit in figure b is well defined?

Here is what I have so far.
For the circuit in figure a. When the bias current changes a bit, Vout changes a lot. However, how to explain the same thing for figure b?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You really need to dive a bit more into this because as it is now you show zero effort in solving this yourself.

Comment: Hi, I have just added what I have so far.

Comment: Simplify even more because then it's more obvious. Assume rop and ron are infinite, assume Vout = Vdd / 2 and try again. Blindly filling in formulas without really understanding what's happening is the path to failure. Then do the same for circuit b.

Comment: I am not applying the formula blindly. I understand what happen in figure a. However, I can not make the same argument for figure b. If rop and ron are infinite, assume Vout = Vdd / 2, then what to do next? Vout = Vdd/2, you assumed everything and I don't know what you meant to do/calculate/understand now.

Comment: Then explain why you need the formula and what the result is. What does it say about Vout ? Assuming a certain condition (like Vout = Vdd/2 ) is a common way to proceed, then you can assume M2 to be in saturation making things easier. When you have a solution check back if that solution supports Vout = Vdd/2 or not. If not, the assumption was wrong, then you know that. But to answer for a you do not need any formula. You have written down the answer already you just don't see it. M1 behaves as a current source and so does M2, so what does this say about Vout ?

Comment: As I said, I understand what happen in figure a. When two current sources with different values in series, the output voltage is undefined. That is idea case when we ignore the output resistances. Including the output resistance, Vout is clearly defined as the formula above. However, Vout changes a lot when the two current sources different. This can cause one of these transistor goes into triode region. I don't understand what is in figure b that makes it output voltage stable? Is the negative feedback?

Comment: Because in figure B the output voltage is Vout = Vdd - Vgs2

Comment: Correct, in **a** Vout is the current difference times the total output resistance Rout. Since Rout is high, only a small current difference makes Vout 0 or Vdd. Keeping Vout on a different voltage requires a feedback loop.

Comment: In **b** the PMOS diode has a stabilizing effect on Vout. Vout will indeed be Vdd - Vgs2. Now consider what Vgs2 will be over the current provided by M1. Note that M2 is always in saturation, that is a property of the diode (why ?).

Comment: I think in figure b, Vout is stable because Vgs2 is relatively constant over a wide range of M1 current. For the second question, M2 is diode connected transistor so Vgd = 0 that is smaller than Vth, the minimum voltage needed to create inversion so M2 is always in saturation.

Comment: *Vgs2 is relatively constant over a wide range of M1 current* Indeed, that is the reason. *M2 is diode connected transistor so Vgd = 0 that is smaller than Vth* Correct again, when connected as a diode, there is no way that Vds can get smaller than Vgs so the transistor **must always** be in saturation (assuming strong inversion mode).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Could you help me with the question below when you have time?
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262471/output-impedance-seen-by-the-inductor