# output impedance seen by the inductor

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, circuit-design, transfer-function

This is an example calculating output resistance that drives the inductor.

Source:Linear Circuit Transfer Functions: An Introduction to Fast Analytical Techniques by Christophe P. Basso

What I am confused is why the input and output are grounded references so they are connected together here as indicated in the red circles?

For calculating output resistance seen by the inductor, should we only short the input 1 so the output resistance will be infinite?

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Why not just calculate seen by the inductor as normal (short input voltage source and leave everything else remain the same as below?
So the resistance seen by inductor is infinity.

[image]
PS: Google book link - page 4:

https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=WGBFjgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Or this online version:

http://dl.4mohandes.com/book/ba/Linear_Circuit_Transfer_Functions.pdf

Comment: I can see the download link given by Anhnha for an "online version" leads to the illegal download of a copyrighted document. Does this contribution comply with the ethic we expect from posters on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's finding the Thevenin resistance across the inductor. It's a two port network and the circuit shown in the figure is equivalent circuit of it. It's equivalent ckt will have lower port of input and output grounded. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network) for all type of equivalent circuits. Since capacitor is getting open circuited and i/p voltage source short circuited we are getting Thevenin resistance as R1 + R2.

Comment: Thank you. However, what I am confused is why lower port of input and output arevgrounded here? Because if it is grounded in the fig 1.3 then C and R2 are useless here. I think the input resistance seen by inductor should be infinite.

Comment: I/p voltage is applied with reference to lower terminal of i/p port, similarly o/p voltage is taken with reference to lower o/p terminal which are grounded in equivalent circuit.

Comment: If you still not getting it take Op-Amp as an example. Even though we apply input voltage to the two terminals but when solving questions we take the negative terminal as reference and similarly we take a ground at the output for reference to the output voltage.

Comment: Thanks. Could you see my update and question in my post? Normally to calculate resistance seen by a component, what we do is set the input source to zero (voltage sources are shorted and current sources are open) and leave everything else remain the same as the picture above?

Comment: If that was an exact circuit then you were right. But this is an equivalent of a two port network. For solving such type of questions we take two references one at the input and other at the output. Then we short the voltage source and open the current source. In some texts they are shown as a single reference also but there we have some dependent source and no other linkage between input and output other than dependent source.

Comment: "But this is an equivalent of a two port network": it is equivalent of the two port network so I don't need to care about what inside the box, just the input and output. Inside the box, they can be anything but what is happening at the input and output ports should be same with a particular network. With figure 1.3, it is a two port network. Now assume that we remove the inductor and it becomes a four port network, two inputs and two outputs. To find the resistance seen by the inductor we should short the other input only. So the input 1 is short.

Comment: However, I still don't see any reason to ground the lower ends of both input and output ports like that.

Comment: You apply a voltage with reference to something. You simply don't apply voltage difference to a network. What is important to remember here is that it is a TECHNIQUE in which voltage is applied with some reference and voltage is taken with some reference. Since, we have a capacitor and a resistor involved at the lower terminals we can't take a common reference. You have to take reference first before seeing into the black box. The same technique is used through out the book. If you are finding it hard to accept, just solve as many questions as you can to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

It was confusing to me at first , when your suggestion to solve this trivial network seems more obvious. Butthis method just uses equivalent circuit methods to demonstrate how it works.

The advantage comes with more complex internal networks and many loops by "loop conversion" methods into a simple single loops, so that computing transfer functions from input/output and reactive part removed permits the impedance or admittance to result in simpler transfer functions to define the DC response, infinite f and mid-range AC Poles and Zero's **without complex alegbra.**

He calls it a ** low entropy method** of simplifying by Thevenin equivalent circuits then finding the equivalent impedance of each reactive part to identify more easily the other elements they resonate with in a current loop. From this he writes  simple LaPlace transforms using Z(s) for impedance from the reduction of network elements into simpler loops.

I can't say I am proficient in this method, but I understand the concept of finding port admittance while grounding the other port sides (one side at a time, not together) and admit this is more of a comment than an answer where more space is available.

I use a **low entropy methods** all the time, converting nonlinear semiconductors into linear models with ESR in order to estimate load regulation, ripple , LED currents, thermal runaway thresholds with physical thermal resistance and electrical ESR, ESR/load ratios, and many other linearization methods of nonlinear circuits.

Here he uses Driving Point voltages with 0 impedance, artificial ground reference points for partial loop admittance and other methods to eliminate complex algebraic terms that have neglible effects in order to find pole/zeros that dominate a transfer function and is adopted with a passion by his reviewer at ON Semi.

Comment: Thank you. For this, "I can't say I am proficient in this method, but I understand the concept of finding port admittance while grounding the other port sides (one side at a time, not together) and admit this is more of a comment than an answer where more space is available" how do you explain the case two port sides are grounded here?