# Current mirror biasing circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, current-mirror

I have just seen the comparator as figure 1 below and I am wondering why don't we use a simplified version as figure 2?

Hope anyone could make it clear.
Thanks.

**Figure 1:**
[image]

**Figure 2**: simplified version

[image]

Comment: You are in principle right that you could use the 2nd circuit also **but** there's something you overlooked ! Look carefully at the geometries of the two PMOSFETs you eliminated. What does this PMOS mirror do with the current Ibias ? So circuit 2 is **NOT** identical unless you make the value of Ibias.... Another reason for using circuit 1 is that you only have this Ibias available from the negative side so you're forced to use a PMOS mirror.

Comment: Yes, actually I ignored the current value or size of MOS, just consider topology. With negative side, do you mean that Ibias is as a current sink?

Comment: I also think that normally Ibias is implemented by a resistor.

Comment: *With negative side, do you mean that Ibias is as a current sink?* Yes I mean that the current is delivered from a NMOS mirror for example. *I also think that normally Ibias is implemented by a resistor* If you can live with up to +/- 20 % variation in bias current over process variations (I'm not even mentioning temperature dependency and supply voltage dependency) then yes, you could use a resistor. But often that bias current will be derived in a different way. Using a resistor is the easiest but usually also gives the least constant Ibias.

Comment: Thanks. So, for example, the current is from NMOS mirror. Then that NMOS mirror also needs Ibias. How can you implement that Ibias so it doesn't depent on power supply, temperature and process?

Comment: *How can you implement that Ibias so it doesn't depend on power supply, temperature and process?* You could write a **thick** book about that ! There is no source which depends on **nothing** so a compromise has to be made. Usually some form of **bandgap circuit** is used to create a temperature compensated voltage, then by combining different types of resistors (with positive and negative temperature dependencies) you could make a reasonable stable bias current. But sometimes, you don't want that, sometimes you need a current which increases over temperature: PTAT !

Comment: Thank you. Could you confirm about my last comment in the thread below.
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262001/common-source-circuit-with-current-source-and-diode-connected-load

Answer (score 1):

Basic function of **current mirror** here is to "**copy**" the Ibias current to main circuit via dividing by 25 (due to transistor sizes 600 vs. 24).

In order to maintain stability of circuit, we generally use transistors in saturation. Very small current may cause transistor *not to saturate*.

We can use transistors to obtain Ibias instead of resistors. If you maintain saturation of transistor (see [diode connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode-connected_transistor)), you can get stable and constant current.